# Openlayer equivalent of Google Map's map.getBounds()

Tags: google-maps, openlayers

In the Google Map's javascript API you can call `map.getBounds().getNorthEast()` or `map.getBounds().getSouthWest()`, which returns the coordindates for the currently *visible* viewport.

Is there an equivalent in OpenLayers?

Comment: Strictly, there are no equivalent functions in OpenLayers, but `OpenLayers.Map.getExtent()` returns the data in a data structure that you can use to calculate these values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[OpenLayers.Map.getExtent()](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.getExtent) is what you're looking for.